# Deleteing Original File After Creating Another

Tags: bash, command-line

Here is the Script I have so far:

```
#! /bin/bash

dd=$(date -v -1d '+%Y-%m-%d')
for file in *.csv ; do
    saveName="${dd} - TF.csv"
    cut -d',' -f5,8 "$file" > "$saveName"   
done
```

The file above would output `2014-02-09 - TF.csv` and the file that created the file is `Campaigns stats for period from Feb 9, 2014 to Feb 9, 2014` I'm trying to delete `Campaigns stats for period from Feb 9, 2014 to Feb 9, 2014` how do I delete this with the script above after it creates `2014-02-09 - TF.csv`

Answer (score 1):

```
cut -d',' -f5,8 "$file" > "$saveName" && rm "$file"
```

Using `&&` (the shell 'and' operator) instead of `;` as the command separator means that the `rm` command is only executed if the `cut` command succeeds.